# Get property types of generic type for use in expression

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a method as part of a generic class for use in the context of querying for a collection of objects where a boolean clause in an expression is met, and the result is ordered by some property on the object type.

The current method signature:

```cs
Task<T> GetFirstWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExp, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> orderByExp)
```

With an example implementation:

```cs
public async Task<T> GetFirstWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExp, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> orderByExp) {
    return await _entities.Where(whereExp)
        .OrderByDescending(orderByExp)  // I would like to use any valid orderByExp type here
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

For use in scenarios like:

```cs
var foundArticleTag = await _tags.GetFirstWhere(
    tag => tag.Name == articleTag, 
    tag => tag.CreatedOn);
```

I would like `orderByExp` function to use any valid type of property on T, rather than explicitly DateTime.  I would prefer not to make the type dynamic, so that only valid types of properties on T might be used. I suppose reflection must be required for this, though I am not sure how to enforce the type constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your method is part of generic type of `T`, you can make your method generic also (accepting another generic type parameter for ordering expression):

```
Task<T> GetFirstWhere<TOrder>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExp, 
    Expression<Func<T, TOrder>> orderByExp);
```

That will require adding the generic parameter to the example implementation:

```
public async Task<T> GetFirstWhere<TOrder>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExp, Expression<Func<T, TOrder>> orderByExp) {
    return await _entities.Where(whereExp)
        .OrderByDescending(orderByExp)  // I would like to use any valid orderByExp type here
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

And usage should remain untouched, cause compiler should be able to infer generic `TOrder` type parameter from the usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as many as generic parameters as you want, so this can be easily extended for a second generic:

```
public async Task<T> GetFirstWhere<T, O>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExp, Expression<Func<T, O>> orderByExp) {
return await _entities.Where(whereExp)
    .OrderByDescending(orderByExp)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: Current method signature does not have any generic parameters, it seems that method is part of generic class.

Comment: @GuruStron, correct, I updated the question to reflect that the method is a member of a generic class.